# Can I provide a const reference to a caller without returning it?

Tags: c++, reference

I'd like to do something conceptually like this.

```
enum class Status {
  READY,
  NOT_READY
};

class Foo {
public:
  Status get_foo(const ExpensiveToCopyType& f) {
    if (is_ready) {
      f = m_foo;
      return Status::READY;
    } else {
      return Status::NOT_READY;
    }
  }
private:
  bool is_ready;
  ExpensiveToCopyType m_foo;
}
```

The important part is that I want to be able to give the caller a read-only handle to `m_foo` and an indication of whether or not it is in a valid state. It will always exist, but it may or may not be in a state that's valid from the caller's context. e.g. consider it's something to be drawn to the screen and might produce visual artifacts if it's "not ready" but won't cause invalid access.

Ostensibly this could be accomplished with a `std::shared_ptr` or the like, but I was wondering if it was possible with references.

Comment: Sounds like you could just return a regular const pointer, or `nullptr` if the status is not ready as a convention.

Comment: Why is "without returning it" important? Is returning a combined state of status and handle not acceptable?

Comment: Reference is not reseatable. That is the main benefit of it. You need copyable or assignable thing like raw pointer, smart pointer or std::reference_wrapper.

Comment: @user17732522 It's a completely valid approach, I'm hoping just to keep clean convention. The entire system uses these status codes to indicate state to callers and I don't want to get into making one-off cases on the return types.

Comment: The simplest way to do this seems to be by returning a pointer, and returning a `nullptr` if the object is not in a valid state.

Comment: You might consider making the members that are expensive to copy mutable and then adding a const member function to perform the expensive operations when they are due.

Comment: Perhaps return a `std::optional<ExpensiveToCopyType>`?

Comment: Or, return a `std::pair<Status, ExpensiveToCopyType*>`

Answer (score 1):

> Can I provide a const reference to a caller without returning it?

No, you cannot. You can provide a pointer instead.

But, I recommend returning the reference (or rather, a pointer) and the validity together. If the reference is useless in the invalid case, then a simple solution is to return only a pointer; null in the case if invalid state.